# I'm trying to build a family tree, how can i join two nodes of different families

Tags: html, css, graph, tree, treeview

I'm trying to create a family tree like something in myheritage.com.
[image: Trying to build something like this]

I've tried and created a graph with nodes, like this: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/6FABZ74W97leCJpQ2qs1

I got stuck while joining 2 different nodes from 2 different families:
[image: Find this image for my requirement]

Comment: show us the code that you have tried.

Comment: Please find this 
https://plnkr.co/edit/6FABZ74W97leCJpQ2qs1

Comment: can anyone help me with this.. i'm almost struck :(